# Justification for different code bases on different branches in the same repo?

Tags: version-control, git, github, branching

Branches in `git` repos or similar are practically always derived from the same code base; after all, they're usually merged back in to `master` later.

But, if you wanted your open source project on GitHub to have a website, you could use [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/), which lets you publish a site in a repo on a branch named `gh-pages`.  Unless said open source project is a frontend web app, `gh-pages` will by necessity *not* be based on `master`.

`gh-pages` is an [orphan branch](https://dev-tips.com/git/orphan-branches-in-git); the branch starts its very own initial commit, and the resulting graph is not connected to the one belonging to the `master` branch.

**Are there any other scenarios where you would want to maintain branches which start their own graphs?**

Comment: It's one of the few things where I think GitHub chose a bad solution. A separate pages repo would be so much cleaner. Why should I bloat a nice small code repo with images and html? It makes no sense.

Comment: I just use headless/orphan branches, which don't share a parent with master: git checkout --orphan gh-pages.  Displays fine on github too.

Comment: @MaulingMonkey That's a thing?

Comment: Also, the lack of answers, while probably a bad thing normally, speaks volumes here.  Here, a lack of answers just means "no".